# How to solve IBM DB2 Golang Connection Error SQL3008N

Tags: go, kubernetes, networking, db2

I have a Golang backend service that use DB2 database to perform a query. I use Docker to containerized the Golang backend app and deploy it on Kubernetes. The Golang app is already running on the production environment.

I got an error when my Golang backend app tried to connect to the DB2 database like below:

```
SQL30081N A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol
being used: "TCP/IP". Communication API being used: "SOCKETS". Location
where the error was detected: "<IP DB2 database>". Communication function detecting the error: "recv".
Protocol specific error code(s): "110", "*", "*". SQLSTATE=08001
```

And here is my Golang code for DB2 connection:

```golang
package config

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

func InitDB2() (*sql.DB, error) {
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf(
        "HOSTNAME=%s;DATABASE=%s;PORT=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;SSLConnection=false",
        viper.GetString("DB2_HOSTNAME"),
        viper.GetString("DB2_DATABASE"),
        viper.GetString("DB2_PORT"),
        viper.GetString("DB2_USERNAME"),
        viper.GetString("DB2_PASSWORD"),
    )

    db2, err := sql.Open("go_ibm_db", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        return db2, err
    }

    err = db2.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        return db2, err
    }

    return db2, nil
}
```

I use this library for the Golang DB2 connection:
https://github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db

These are several solution that I have done:

1. The firewall between the Kubernetes firewall to the DB2 has opened and allowed, I have tested through telnet/ping from the Kubernetes worker node to the DB2 IP address and it is connected
2. I have set the DB2 registry variable `DBCOMM=TCPIP` on the DB2 database

However the error still happened.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is only about configuration. The 110 error (of SQL20081N) is a TIMEOUT.  This is usually a configuration matter. Examine the Db2-server diagnostics, to see if there is evidence of a connection.

Comment: State 8001 means you failed security. Looks like you will need a real username and password to connect.

Comment: @mao hi, thanks for the reply and clearing it out that my Golang DB2 connection code has no problem. According to your suggestion, I haven't checked the DB2 Server diagnostics, therefore let me check it and let you know the result

Comment: @JamesAnderson hi, what do you mean by need a real username and password ? Because I can access the DB2 on the terminal using the credential which I used currently. But I'll re-check the credential again, I am also not sure if the connection need SSL though, thanks.

Comment: sqlstate 08001 means "The connection was unable to be established to the application server or other server". Your question explicitly excludes SSL (sslConnection=false).  It's fundamental to know whether your connection is encrypted or not (and if encrypted to use the correct port-number, and certificate file(s)). It is unclear whether you can access Db2 from the terminal on the same hostname as your golang client is running (this is the only valid test), or from a terminal on your own workstation.

Comment: @mao so the error also might be caused I didn't provide the SSL, if the DB2 connection required it ?

Comment: @mao and about the DB2 access, I can access the DB2 from the terminal in the same OS/machine where the DB2 installed. Between the Golang app and the DB2 they are on the different cluster and server, therefore I can confirm that the Golang app access to the DB2 use different hostname.

Comment: Most likely your docker container that runs the golang backend is incorrectly configured. You have to shell into __that__ container to test the connectivity (for example, by editing the db2dsdriver.cfg and attempting to connect with `db2cli`. Refer to the online Db2-docs for details.  Basic problem determination required.

Comment: @mao so I still need to configure the db2cli and db2dsdriver.cfg manually even though I have defined it on the code connection string?

Comment: the only reason for configuring db2dsdriver.cfg manually is to test db2-connectivity directly at clidriver level (i.e. independently of golang). In other words if clidriver cannot connect, then *nothing* built on top of clidriver will connect either.  But first sanity check the container start arguments, ports mapping, firewall status as they are more likely suspects for configuration errors.

Comment: @mao okay, so which configuration should I define between the <dnscollection>, the <database>, and the <parameters>? Is it only the <database> one, should be enough?